# Loading image is not showing in OnStart event of the Canvas App

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp, image, powerapps-forms, powerapps-canvas

I am setting Loading image true and false in the OnStart event of the Canvas app and using that variable in the visible property of the image, but the loading gif image is not showing while app loading.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in Advance!

```
OnStart event

//Display Loading Screen
Set(
    LoadingSpin,
    true
);

Other Formulas

//hide Loading Screen
Set(
    LoadingSpin,
    false
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your formula seems fine to me. Make sure you have configured below things correctly:

1. Set `Visible` property of image control to `LoadingSpin`.
2. Image control is at the front of all other controls on your screen. If not, use **Bring to front/Bring forward** to bring it to the front.

If everything is correct, there might be the possibility that execution time for your "Other Formulas" is less & that's why you are not able to see the loading image.

Comment: Hi Ganesh, 
What we should do if the execution time is less?

Comment: I am not sure if you can do much in that case. Also, if the execution time is less & controls are updated immediately, there is no need to show the loading image, right?

Comment: Hi @, does this answer help you in any way? If Yes, Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily.